# Prove that in any simple graph with more than one vertex, there must be two vertices with the same degree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that in any simple graph with more than one vertex, there must be two vertices with the same degree.

-A direct proof seems incorrect to me.

-My next guess would be to solve this via contradiction, but I am not sure how? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If there are $n$ vertices, the only possible degrees are the $n$ numbers $0,1,\ldots,n-1$. Can the graph have both a vertex of degree $0$ and a vertex of degree $n-1$?

Comment: I would think not?

Comment: @D.Peterson: Correct. (Can you explain why?) Now use the pigeonhole principle.